# Weird display freeze after logout, or when cold booting after shutdown - Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

Tags: boot, freeze, plymouth, logout

Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. Asus ROG G751-J, Nvidia GTX965M. After logging out from user in Gnome desktop, the screen freezes on splash art. Same happens after a cold boot following a total shutdown. Not with reboot though. The graphical login screen is frozen and I can't see my user account prompt. However, I can still change TTY terminals during the display freeze using ctl + alt + F-key. From here I can `sudo reboot` and get it working again

I tried installing and switching to `lightdm`, didn't work. Then, doing both at once, so I don't know which one fixed it, I uninstalled `nvidia-driver-515` meta-package and installed `nvidia-driver-510` (this one I know works fine on my graphics card from previous experience), and also changed this line in `/etc/default/grub` to remove the splash screen(s):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

change to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

Technically, Nvidia driver v.515 supports my card on manufacturer's website, but doing these two things fixed it. I don't know which one it is and I don't want to try to recreate it to potentially break something, as this is my main workstation. **I am posting this for others who may have this problem**, and to raise awareness in case this specific issue is due to the newer Nvidia drivers. But maybe it just has to do with the splash and not with the driver.

Comment: This is not how this site works. It is a question and answer site. You pose a question and someone gives you an answer. You do not put the answer with the question. What you can do is after posting your question you choose the option at the bottom of the question called answer your own question. You put the answer there.

Comment: I did, but it forced me to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer. I changed my answer to directly include the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, the following fixed the issue:

1. uninstalling `nvidia-driver-515` and instead installing `nvidia-driver-510`
2. editing the following line in `/etc/default/grub`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

changed to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

By rolling back the driver and removing the splash screen during boot, there is no more freezing.